# How to expand picture to cover entire header area? (twenty-twelve theme)

Tags: theme-twenty-twelve

I am running twenty-twelve theme and have applied a header background on the .site-title class. Header shows up but  it's width is only 960px.

How do I disable the left and right margins/padding of this theme so I can expand the picture to cover entire header area? ( I don't know what css code to add)

Here's a picture if it makes more sense: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ae8b6.jpg

Thank you in advance!

Comment: This is basic CSS and should probably not be in the WordPress section. Try [finding out how to make a full-width header](https://google.com/search?q=full+width+header+css) and use `style.css` in the Twenty Twelve theme to add the proper style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to do a lot of modifications on this one.

We are going to modify header.php file

Firstly move this piece of code from header tag file to below body tag

```
 <?php if ( get_header_image() ) : ?>
    <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>"><img src="<?php header_image(); ?>" class="header-image" width="<?php echo get_custom_header()->width; ?>" height="<?php echo get_custom_header()->height; ?>" alt="" /></a>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

wrap this code in a div

```
 <div class="header-full-width">
  <?php if ( get_header_image() ) : ?>
    <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>"><img src="<?php header_image(); ?>" class="header-image" width="<?php echo get_custom_header()->width; ?>" height="<?php echo get_custom_header()->height; ?>" alt="" /></a>
    <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
```

Now add css

```
.header-full-width img {
 width: 100%;
}
```

This should do the trick.